# Localhost refused to connect Wamp

Tags: php, android, localhost, wamp

I am using Wamp64 with text.php file in android_connect within www in wamp64 folder on a Windows 7 system (64-bit). However, on typing localhost/android_connect/text.php in both Chrome and Internet Explorer, it states that localhost refused to connect. Have tried 127.0.0.1 as well and existing alternatives as mentioned in [WAMP: Cannot Connect To Localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936982/wamp-cannot-connect-to-localhost), and changing port 80 to 8080 with no avail. Please help.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083979/wamp-server-doesnt-load-localhost

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the error.log and access.log files;
Also, open the console, run the command:

```
netstat -nao
```

And check that port 80 is being used by another application.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue in WAMP64 3.1.9 - my site's directory name inside of the www folder included an underscore as yours does. Renaming the site directory and removing the underscore did the trick for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the specific Ip address of your device.